# Found some square boxes in a xliff file and not sure what they are?

Tags: box, xliff

I'm looking at a xliff file and found some weird boxes which I don't know what they are? (Please see screenshot)

[image]

Do you guys have any ideas what the weird bug boxes are?

Thank you very much and I'm looking forward to your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen that character, but here is how I would go about finding out what it is:

The first thing to do is to check the source and target language of the XLIFF file, which should be defined in the XLIFF header. Perhaps this character is a valid character in either the source or the target language script.

The next step depends on whether you can contact the person who created the XLIFF file. If yes, you can show them what the file looks like for you and ask them if the file has perhaps been garbled during transmission.

If not, you could check the encoding of the XLIFF file. If it is UTF-16, just open the file in a hex editor, find the code point for this character, and look it up on [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/charts/). If the file is encoded as UTF-8 open it in Notepad++ (or any other text editor that allows you to change the encoding), convert it to UTF-16, then proceed as described above.

If you don't know the encoding of the file it becomes a matter of guessing. You can look at some other <trans-units> (assuming that there are more than this one in your XLIFF file): if they contain other extended characters and they are displayed correctly your editor has probably guessed the right encoding, and you can convert to Unicode and look up the character code. Different text editors have different ways of guessing encodings: try a few.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that those characters are the result of an encoding conversion error, which are commonly called [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

It's also possible this is some sort of emoji or unusual glyph that's not rendering correctly in your editor.  This would be unusual, but given that it appears to be a UI string, it might be possible.